# I am using UIActivityViewController , But it rotates images if I share it on Facebook, Email etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share images.
As it share image on facebook or email. Then image gets rotate. Why it is so ?

My Code is as follows:
ShareArr contains image objects

```
ActivityViewCustomActivity *aVCA = [[ActivityViewCustomActivity alloc]init];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareArr applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aVCA]];
[controller setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) { }];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Show your code for `UIActivityViewController` and image to share.

Comment: ShareArr contains image objects
   `ActivityViewCustomActivity *aVCA = [[ActivityViewCustomActivity alloc]init];
                UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareArr applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aVCA]];
[controller setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
                    
                   
                    
                }];
                [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: What did you do to make sure your image is not rotated before sharing?

Comment: Image is in right format on imageview. & it is showing right in dialog of facebook & twitter but as I share it. It gets rotate on facebook/twiiter

Comment: This is because portrait images are stored in the library sideways, and there is an EXIF flag in the image to park it as needing to be rotated. I don't know how to solve it yet. We need some way to set that EXIF data in the image that is given to UIActivityViewController

Comment: @Nilesh_iOSDev did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked awhile ago but I ran into the same problem and here is my solution.

I found this site [bug in UIActivityViewController](http://www.openradar.me/12034547)

Here is the paragraph that I found useful from the site,

> Notes: It seems when the system converts the UIImage into an NSData for the MFMailComposeViewController (and other UIActivities) it does NOT preserve the orientation information. This is why when an NSData is passed in, it is rotated correctly as the system doesn't have to convert it.

So here is part of the code I was using in my case (taking a photo),

```
 NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Then the facebook function from the UIActivityViewController was taking the UIImage and converting that back into NSData. So what I did was use the NSData *imageData and put that directly into my activityViewController.

Hope this helps someone.